# Share my Mac’s internet connection (WiFi) with my iPad or iPhone via Lightning cable

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, internet-sharing

I seem to remember connecting my iPad or iPhone to my MacBook Pro laptop using a [Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)) cable. From there I was able to let the iOS device access the internet via the Mac’s existing WiFi connection.

> [internet]↔[WiFi]↔[MacBook]↔[Lightning cable]↔[iOS device]

I vaguely recall using `System Preferences` > `Sharing` > `Internet Sharing`. But I see only `Thunderbolt Bridge` and `Bluetooth PAN` items, nothing for over the Lightning cable.

[image: screen shot of System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing]

If the Lightning cable cannot be made to work, might the `Bluetooth PAN` item let the iOS devices us a wireless [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) connection to use the Mac’s internet connection?

Using macOS Sierra, and iOS 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check `System Preferences` > `Network`

There appears to be a problem with your network configuration. You should indeed have seen a `iPhone USB` item in that list of “Ports”.

Check your `System Preferences` > `Network` settings. On the left you should see an item for the network interface name something like “iPhone USB”. If not, try using the `Location` popup menu at top to `Edit Locations` and add a new location. Alternatively, you might try the `+` icon button to add an interface of that type to that list.

[image: screenshot of System Preferences > Network]

Now go back to your `System Preferences` > `Sharing` > `Internet Sharing` where you should now see an item named something like `iPhone USB`.

[image: screenshot of System Preferences > Sharing]

From there, turn on the `Internet Sharing` checkbox to start sharing. If it does not work, try rebooting your iPhone (hold down Power/Sleep button).

You can test to be certain by turning off your iPhone’s Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and Cellular Data. If you have internet access, then you must be using the USB cable connection to access the internet over your Mac’s Wi-Fi connection.