# Priority of cellular data versus USB/Bluetooth sharing of Mac’s internet connection on iOS

Tags: macos, ios, mac, cellular-data, internet-sharing

An iOS device such as iPhone or iPad can share the internet connection of a Mac by either connecting with a USB cable or connecting via Bluetooth, as discussed [in this Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/322772/17907).

[image: screenshot of System Preferences > Sharing]

If I want to be sure that I am using the shared internet access of the Mac, I can shut off cellular data in `Settings` on the iOS device.

Instead, is there a way to prioritize the use of the shared internet access over that of the cellular data? Is that default behavior?

NOTE: The subject of this Question is **not [*tethering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering)** where the Mac uses the iPhone’s internet connection. We are talking about the opposite: *the iPhone is using the Mac’s internet connection*.

Comment: I've never heard of doing this. I just tried it on my phone and I don't get internet over USB. Methinks maybe you are thinking about the opposite? A mac sharing an iPhone's internet connection over USB?

Comment: Nope, I mean sharing the Mac’s wifi connection with my iOS device. See this Question, [*Share my Mac’s internet connection (WiFi) with my iPad or iPhone via Lightning cable*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322772/share-my-mac-s-internet-connection-wifi-with-my-ipad-or-iphone-via-lightning-c).  See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePEAM.png).

Comment: Have you tried changing the connections priorities in System Preferences > Network (left side) using the cog wheel?

Comment: @oa- I am not talking about prioritizing the Mac’s network connections; the Mac has only one connection, the Wi-Fi as shown in the dialog box of the Question. I suspect you are confused about my scenario and are thinking about "tethering" where the Mac uses the iPhone's internet connection. My Question is the opposite: **the iPhone is using the Mac’s internet connection**.