# iPad USB-C Internet Connection: Tethering to Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, usb, tethering, internet-sharing

I have an iPad Pro (2018 3rd Gen) with a USB-C Port and a 2018 Macbook Pro with a USB-C Port. Can I tether the iPad to my Macbook's Internet connection using a USB-C cable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a USB-C cable to share Macbook's Internet connection with the iPad [just like the USB to lightning cable does on iPhones and older iPads.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322772/)

### Benefits:

- The USB-C cable powers the iPad directly from the Macbook reducing the number of mains sockets you need to just one.
- WiFi & Bluetooth can be completely turned off on the iPad.
- Traffic is proxied to the iPad via the Macbook (*which has a firewall in front of it*).

### Negatives:

- ***Airdrop*** and ***Sidecar*** will not work with your wireless interfaces down.

### Parts Required:

- Standard USB-C charging cable that came with your iPad will work
- Or this short (and tidy) [Anker USB-C](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B076D76DRQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) cable I've found works well

### Internet Connection:

You Macbook should have a non-802.1x Internet connection to share, ie: straight WiFi.  If your WiFi connection is secured using EAP-TLS (with certificates) or other 802.1X security to stop this sort of thing, the USB-C Internet connection sharing won't work.

### Configuration:

On Macbook Pro: "***System Preferences***" > "***Sharing***" > "***Internet Sharing***" and tick "***iPad USB***" as below:

[image: System Preferences Sharing Dialog]

Connect the USB-C cable between them and you're done.

[image: USB-C Anker Cable]

It's a tidy, secure solution.